# How to properly use es6 classes in different files by importing them in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, module, browserify, ecmascript-6

I have recently discovered Meteor and I am struggling with using ES6 classes and imports in a new Meteor project. What I want to do is to have a complex structure of classes, which methods get called from Meteor events/methods/helpers. I've added Babel.js to the project by writing a command `$ meteor add grigio:babel` and it works properly.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

in server/models/article.js:

```
class Article {
  static all() {
    //returns all articles from db
  }
}
```

in server/methods/articles.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
  allArticles: {
    Article.all();
  }
})
```

Having just that raises `ReferenceError: Article is not defined` in a methods file, which is adequate. So I have got three options: write all classes in one file, append all classes to a global object or use a good module system like Browserify. Obviously, third option is better.

But how do I use that? Babel converts `export`, `import` into Browserify by default and Meteor raises a `require is not defined` error on page refresh. After googling the problem I didn't find a clear solution on how to add Browserify to Meteor. Should I add a npm packages support to Meteor, add a npm package of browserify and add it manually to Meteor on every page where I import/export anything? Or should I use a completely different approach? How is this task usually handled in Meteor? Thank you!

Comment: Use the .es6 extension instead of .js for any files containing es6 ECMAScript 2015 code. This fixed a similar ReferenceError for me. If it works for you I'll add this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

I was reading about this earlier and found [this issue](https://github.com/grigio/meteor-babel/issues/9) on github that may help.

Essentially just assign the class to a variable that is exposed to both the client and server (lib/both/etc depends on your file structure). Like so:

```
Article = class Article {...}
```

Seems to be the best solution at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately using that just exposes Article to a global namespace, which leads to namespace pollution. So if I go global path, I would rather use a  namespace, like
`website.Article = class Article {...}`

Comment: Indeed. Still not an unreasonable solution, might be enough for a long while

Comment: Meteor 1.2 will support it. ["We will replace Meteor's homegrown, pre-ES15 namespacing system with shiny, modern ES15 modules."](http://info.meteor.com/blog/whats-coming-in-meteor-12-and-beyond)

Comment: @corvid Modules are coming but not in 1.2. If you read a little later in that article — "we're adding support for all its features except for modules"

Answer (score 4):

The way I do this is to collect objects together into various namespaces, for example:

```js
// Global
Collections = {};
```

```js
class Article {
  static all() {
    //returns all articles from db
  }
}

_.extend(Collections, { Article });
```

Then to avoid having to use `Collections.Article` everywhere I can use the following in the file I need to access `Article` in:

```js
// Make `Article` available
let { Article } = Collections;
```

Comment: not sure to follow the let { Article } = Collections, care to expand a bit?

Comment: Sure. It's Object destructuring assignment — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

I am using Meteor 1.4.1.1 and the error remains, when reproducing your approach. However, there are some new ways to use es6 classes now:

**1. Export your class as a constant (e.g. for use as a singleton object):**

```
class MyModuleInternalClassName {
   //... class internals
}
export const PublicClassName = new MyModuleInternalClassName();
```

You can import this one via

```
import {PublicClassName} from 'path/to/PublicClassFileName.js';
```

**2. Export your class directly as the module's default**

```
export default class PublicClassName {
   //... class internals
}
```

and then import it (as with the above one) as the following

```
import {PublicClassName} from from 'path/to/PublicClassFileName.js';
let myInstance = new PublicClassName();
```

**+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++**

Regarding the question of OP and the error, you can try something like this:

**Article.js**

```
class InternalArticle {
  constructor(){
     //setup class
  }

  all() {
    //returns all articles from db
  }
  register(article){
     //add article to db
  }
}
export const Article = new InternalArticle();
```

**Import and use the Singleton**

```
import {Article} from 'path/to/Article.js';

//either register some article
Article.register(someArticle);


//or get all your articles
const allArticles = Article.all();
```

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: @afkatja I improved my answer. Does this help you with your problem? Maybe you otherwise should create a new question on SO.